# FFmpeg: Record the screen but only remember the last 5 minutes?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-capture, screen-capture, pyffmpeg

I am using Ffmpeg to continuously record the video the screen on my PC. However, I only ever need the last 5 minutes of the video.

Yes, I could edit the video afterwards. But these recording sessions could go on for several hours and take up A LOT of hard disk space.

Is there a way to only remember the last 5 minutes of a video capture and forget everything previous **before the file is saved**? (Kind of like a TiVO would do)

I've found

```
-fs limit_size
```

and

```
-timelimit duration
```

..but these seem to stop once the limit has been reached. Maybe there is an inversed switch?  Like to only keep the last 1000000 bytes or something.

Comment: No such feature as far as I know. Consider submitting a patch implementing this or making a feature request on the [bug tracker](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/). One option is to use the [segment muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) with the `-segment_time` option then somehow dispose of the old segments according to your requirements.

Comment: It's possible with `segment` muxer: `-f segment -segment_time 60 -segment_wrap 2 output%d.mkv`. Thanks to @Gyan. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63243437/704244).

Answer (score 4):

I agree that I would love to see this feature in ffmpeg.

As a work around solution, I created a script to record the screen into pictures and continuously delete older pictures. Unfortunately it doesn't save audio. Here is the script.

```
#!/bin/bash 
set -e -u

mkdir "$HOME/history" || true
rm "$HOME"/history/img*.png || true

# Get screen resolution.
RES="$(xwininfo -root | grep -Po 'geometry[^+]*' | sed 's/^\S* //')"

# Record the screen into images into /home/username/history/ one per second.
avconv -s "$RES" -f x11grab -i :0.0 -r 1  -f image2 "$HOME/history/img%06d.png" &

AVCONV_PID=$!

trap "kill $AVCONV_PID" INT TERM EXIT

while true; do
    # Delete screen images older than 5 minutes.
    find "$HOME/history" -name "img*.png" -mmin +5 -exec rm {} +
    sleep 10
done
```

If you want 5 pictures per second, change the part `-r 1` to `-r 5`. See this link [how to assemble the images into a video (avi, mpeg) file](https://superuser.com/questions/624567/ffmpeg-create-a-video-from-images).

PS.
You could also use ffmpeg instead of avconv.

Answer (score 4):

*Thank you [@bartolo-otrit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704244/bartolo-otrit) for the right track.*

It took a long time but I've figured out what seems like a really efficient way to do this.

## Alternatives

- The naive solution would be a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). This might be possible, but it surely doesn't feel practical as I can't anything online about doing so.
- You could also somehow remove data from the beginning of a file when it gets too long, but I don't think that's possible while the file is being written to.
- [@Sepero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24392225/18032774) is a great workaround, but I really wanted to be able to eventually include audio, so I explored a fully native ffmpeg solution.

This is where the `segment` ffmpeg format comes in.

## Concept

Let's say that we only want to keep the last 5 seconds of data.

The idea is that we write 5 seconds worth of data to **File A**, then start writing  the next 5 seconds to **File B**. When we reach 10 seconds, we start overwriting the next 5 seconds onto **File A** (because we already have the last 5 seconds in **File B**), and so on. We'll always have the last 5 seconds across either of the two files, and we only have an overhead of 10 seconds at most. This prevents us from needing to store hours worth of screen recording, only to trim off the last N seconds/minutes.

After we have the two segments, we can combine them into one file <= 10 seconds long. Then we can trim the last 5 seconds from that file.

---

I'm using **Windows 11** and **ffmpeg version n4.3.1-29**.

### 1. Record Screen Into Segments

This will constantly record your desktop using gdigrab and pass that input into segment. Segment will create two files named segment0.mp4 and segment1.mp4, and a catfile.ffcat to help combine them later.

You can stop this command with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> or by typing <kbd>q</kbd>, then <kbd>enter</kbd>.

```js
ffmpeg -y -f gdigrab -video_size 1920x1080 -show_region 1 -i desktop \
  -f segment -segment_time 300 -segment_format mp4 -segment_list catfile.ffcat \
  -segment_wrap 2 -reset_timestamps 1 segment%d.mp4
```

I'm not an ffmpeg expert, but I'll try to explain what each part of the command does:

`-y` - Responds yes (Y) to any prompts ffmpeg asks. I use it to automatically overwrite any existing files from previous runs.

`-f` - Stands for *format*. It's used to force the following input/output into the specified ffmpeg format. From what I can tell, this flag is often optional so some people leave it out. I think it really helps with readability, so I'd recommend including in the command.

`gdigrab` - A Windows-only format used for recording your desktop. You can try switching this out for one of the formats for macOS or Linux by referring to [this guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop).

`-video_size` - An option for gdigrab that specifies the screen size (gdigrab has a ton of helpful options you might like, see [this link](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#gdigrab)).

`-show_region 1` - Option for gdigrab that shows an outline around the part of your screen currently being recorded.

`-i desktop` - **desktop** is a keyword to capture your entire screen. If you don't specify the **video_size**, this command will record every monitor in one really wide video, which likely isn't preferable.

`segment` - Goes over my head for the most part, but the segment format is for splitting input among *segments* of smaller video files of a predefined length (see [the segment docs here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment)).

`-segment_time 300` - How long each video segment is in seconds. I set it to 300s, which comes out to 5 minutes. Note that this will likely be off by a few seconds (presumably due to encoding requirements). I tried setting it to 5 seconds, and my video segments ended up being ~7s long instead. Shouldn't be a big deal, but it's worth noting.

`-segment_format mp4` - The file format you're going to output in. I used mp4 and I've seen others use mkv, but I'm not sure what others are supported with segment.

`-segment_list catfile.ffcat` - This part of the command is super cool. It creates a special .ffcat file (I chose the name "catfile" but you can call it whatever). It keeps track of the order of your output segments. Otherwise, you have to figure out what order to recombine them in, which isn't fun.

`-segment_wrap 2` - Only create up to two segments. After it fills up the second segment, it starts overwriting the first. This ensures that you'll never lose data newer than `segment_time`. If you don't specify this value, it'll keep creating new segment files and never delete the old data, which defeats the purpose of this strategy.

`-reset_timestamps 1` - I don't entirely understand what this does, but it seems to help when combining the segments back together.

`segment%d.mp4` - This is your output file name. The `%d` is important for the segment format to work correctly. It basically creates new segments using that file name, replacing the %d with the current segment index. You should end up with two files: "segment0.mp4" and "segment1.mp4".

### 2. Combine the Segments Back Together

*From [@Gyan's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41297944/18032774)*

Once we've created two chunks, we can easily combine them into one file by leveraging our catfile created in the previous command.

I don't know the fine details of this one, but `-c copy` is explained [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy).

```js
ffmpeg -y -i catfile.ffcat -map 0 -c copy combined.mp4
```

### 3. Get the Last 5 Minutes

*From [@llogan's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36120894/18032774)*.

Trim the last 5 minutes. Like I said, we have a video that's guaranteed to be between 5 - 10 minutes long, so we should have no problem trimming down the last 5 minutes.

```js
ffmpeg -y -sseof -300 -i combined.mp4 output.mp4
```

### 4. Remove the Tempoary Files

You'll need to delete this extra files yourself after the operation. You can run:

```js
rm catfile.ffcat segment0.mp4 segment1.mp4 combined.mp4
```

---

Very long-winded answer but I really wished I had something like it when I was looking, so I hope that this knowledge helps someone else!