# How to remove first 15 seconds and last 10 seconds of several video files in windows?

Tags: video, video-processing, video-editing

I have lots of small video lectures but the first and last few seconds are the opening and ending credits which I don't wish to keep. Moreover, it breaks continuity.

So what I want is to remove first 15 seconds and last 10 seconds of all video files and then merge them.

Can anyone suggest a way or software to do that ?

Comment: you can read through the docs of this great tool FFmpeg [https://www.ffmpeg.org/documentation.html](https://www.ffmpeg.org/documentation.html) it's has a CLI that allows you to do bulk work onto files you can write up a small program via (.NET, Node.js (gulp), Golang) or just use the tool itself to work on bulk files or powershell if you're familiar with scripting. `FFmpeg -i source_video.mpg -ss 00:00:10 -t 00:00:30 final_video.mpg` example of a command to trim

Comment: This is a bit broad. An addition to Andrei's good recommendation. Depending on the container (e.g. MP4), there are at least two types of doing this: cut frame-exact which needs re-encoding or not (maybe only key-frame based then) without re-encoding. The details are probably found in ffmpeg's docs.

Answer (score 0):

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options

- -ss position (input/output)

  **can remove first 15 seconds**: `-ss "0:00:15"` or `-ss 15`
- -to position (input/output)

  from pos to **pos**
- -t duration (input/output)

  from pos with **dur**
- -sseof position (input)

  `-sseof -10`: get last 10 seconds, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36120894/10298463

**but doesn't has `-toeof position`.**

I think it can calc by `ffprobe "infile" 2>&1 | grep -Eo "([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}"`, then use option `-t`