# How can I use ffmpeg to save only the last 60 secs recorded?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I'm trying to figure out a way to use ffmpeg command to save only the last 60 seconds recorded.
The way I'm doing it now is using a thread to record 60 seconds videos, and then merge the last two videos and cut the last 60 seconds (using the -t command), the method I'm trying to achieve should not save multiple videos and then merge and cut.

Below the command I'm using:

`ffmpeg -sseof 60 -i "\PATH\TO\VIDEO" -c copy "\PATH\TO\OUTPUT"`

Comment: Ok, so it's not working as you hoped, What result do you get from you command line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FFMPEG: get last 10 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36120709/ffmpeg-get-last-10-seconds)